# Given two (possibly dependent) random variables, writing one as a sum of two r.v.s

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose we have two random variables, $X$ and $Y$, that may be dependent. Can we find a random variable, $Z$, such that,

$$X = \mathbb{E}[X\vert Y] + Z \quad a.s.$$ where $Z$ is independent of $Y$?

Comment: $Z_1=X$ and $Z_2=0$. (unless $X$ is a  constant r.v.).

Comment: you are right! Just edited.

Comment: You have already defined $Z$. So your question just asks if $Y$ is independent of $X-E(X|Y)$.

Comment: The answer is negative in general. A sufficient condition is that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly Gaussian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, taking expectations we deduce $$ E[X] = E[E[X|Y]] + E[Z] \implies E[Z] =0$$

Similarly, multiplying by $Y$ and taking expectation we deduce

$$E[Y Z] = 0$$

Hence $Z$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated. This is basically [the orthogonality principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality_principle) (the "prediction error" is uncorrelated with the data).

Of course, this does not imply independence. It would if $X,Y$ (and hence $Z$) are jointly gaussian.

Answer (score 1):

As @zhoraster said the answer is negative in general. Counter-example: Take $X:= C\cdot Y$ where $C$ and $Y$ are independent RVs. Then $X-E(X|Y) = CY -YE(C) = Y(C-E(C))$. If $C$ and $Y$ are not a.s. constant $Y$ is not independent of $Y(C-E(C))$ which by @Kavi Rama Murthy 's comment answers the question.